# PHP CLI: Possible to set a $_SERVER Variable that's an Array?

Tags: php, bash, symfony, command-line-interface, magento2

When running PHP from the command line in `bash`, is it possible to set a `$_SERVER` variable that it, itself, an array?

That is, if I do something like this

```
$ export test=foo
```

and then run a program like this

```
<?php
#File: test.php
var_dump($_SERVER['test']);
```

the program will output the string value "foo".  Is it possible to have `$_SERVER['test']` be equal to a PHP array **without** extra PHP code?

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is I have a Symfony CLI based program I can't modify, and this program uses the `$_SERVER` variables to bootstrap its enviornment.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\Shell\ComplexParameter;
//...
$bootstrapParam = new ComplexParameter(self::INPUT_KEY_BOOTSTRAP);
$params = $bootstrapParam->mergeFromArgv($_SERVER, $_SERVER);
$params[Bootstrap::PARAM_REQUIRE_MAINTENANCE] = null;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

The `Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);` recognizes some nested keys in `$params` -- I'm trying to find a way to change those values without modifying the CLI program itself.

Comment: Have you considered creating a configuration file, for example a JSON file you can read in the script and edit as needed?

Comment: Use the [mod_env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html) module

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thank you for your engagement, but per the question I can't change the PHP code here.  Yes, normally I'd use a PHP based config, or PHP code that read a config from another value.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thank you for your engagement, however, per the question, I'm running PHP from the command line free of apache.  While mod_env is great for running things from a web context, it doesn't address my concerns.

Comment: You can try the composer features in order to [Using environment variables to set the parameters](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler#using-environment-variables-to-set-the-parameters). Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

you can set any server variable via **.htaccess** file or apache **.conf** file, you can do it using [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)

```
SetEnv MY_EXAMPLE myexample_data
```

Then you can access that variable in php file

```
echo $_SERVER["MY_EXAMPLE"]; //outputs myexample_data
```

or while using PHP CLI
you can set **$_SERVER**  variable using followings

```
putenv('MY_EXAMPLE=myexample_data');
```

Comment: useful info, but I want to be able to set a value in `MY_EXAMPLE` that is, itself, a PHP array.  Does `.htaccess`, `http.conf`, or `mod_env` support that?

Comment: @AlanStorm none of `.htaccess` `http.conf` `mod-env` apply to cli. Do you need it for cli or for web scripts?

Answer (score 1):

[mergeFromArgv](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Shell/ComplexParameter.php#L86) does not use whole `$_SERVER` array, but only `$_SERVER['argv']` part of it, which is basically command line arguments as scalars.

The arguments seems to be parsed with [parse_str](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1ade3b769a937f19682bbbe4e51b6c956147952f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Shell/ComplexParameter.php#L73) then, so you should be able to pass a php array `a` as following:

```
php yourscript.php a[]=1\&a[]=2\&a[b]=anything
```

You may need to quote the string or escape characters depending on your shell.

Comment: +1 for useful info, and for pointing out my incorrect `mergeFromArgv`.  Still leaving it open to see if there's a way bash can send arrays into $_SERVER though.

Comment: But `mergeFromArgv($_SERVER, $_SERVER);` does exactly that. It merges parsed `$_SERVER['argv']` into `$_SERVER`. Just put your `test=foo` as command line arguments.